# using threads in opencv

Tags: c, multithreading, opencv

im detecting coloured balls in a video feed using opencv. i am recording the circles centre points. when the white ball moves i would like to do a detection for 10 seconds while displaying the video feed. after the 10 seconds i would like the next piece of code to run. im having trouble with this. code follows

```
while(1) 
{
    img = cvQueryFrame( capture );

    CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 7, 45, 40,0,25);

    float* p;
    CvScalar s,t;
    int num_red = 15;


    for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
    {
         // round the floats to an int
         p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
         cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
         int radius = cvRound(p[2]);

         //uchar* ptr;
         //ptr = cvPtr2D(img, center.y, center.x, NULL);
         //printf("B: %d G: %d R: %d\n", ptr[0],ptr[1],ptr[2]);


         s = cvGet2D(img,center.y-6, center.x);
         t = cvGet2D(img,center.y, center.x);//colour of circle
        printf("\nB: %f G: %f R: %f\n",s.val[0],s.val[1],s.val[2]);

        if (s.val[2]<50 && s.val[1]<50 && s.val[0] <50)
        {
            printf("Black Ball\n");

        }
        else if(s.val[2]>200 && s.val[1]>200 && s.val[0]>200)
        {
            printf("White Ball\n"); 
            xpos=center.x;
            ypos=center.y;
        }
        else if(s.val[2]>=250 && s.val[1]>=250 && s.val[0] <200)
            printf("Yellow Ball\n");
        else if(s.val[2]<70 && s.val[1]>80 && s.val[0] <70)
            printf("Green Ball\n");
        else if(s.val[2]>100 && s.val[1]<100 && s.val[0] <100)
            printf("Brown Ball\n");
        else if(s.val[2]<100 && s.val[1]<100 && s.val[0] >100)
            printf("Blue Ball\n");
        else if(s.val[2]>=250 && s.val[1]<250 && s.val[0] >=250)
            printf("Pink Ball\n");
        else if (s.val[2]<=255 && s.val[2]>=0 && s.val[1]<=255 && s.val[1]>=0 && s.val[0] <=255 && s.val[0]>=0)
        {
            printf("Red Ball\n");
            //num_red++;
        }

         // draw the circle center
         cvCircle(img, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );

         // draw the circle outline
         cvCircle(img, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );

         //display coordinates
         printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius);
    }

    printf("\nDetected %d balls\n", circles->total);

    if (xpos >= oldx + 10 || xpos<= oldx - 10 //wait for white ball movement here.
        && ypos >= oldy + 10 || ypos<= oldy - 10)
    {
        oldx = xpos;
        oldy = ypos;
        printf("White Ball Moving");

        //start 10second counter where balls are tracked and video displayed
        //after 10 seconds next code runs 
    }

    {
        //code to be run after 10 seconds counter but ony then
    }

}//end of while there is frame incoming

cvShowImage( "Vid", img );
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: at the end of my code, i have commented that i would like to be able to wait 10 seconds after white ball begins to move. during these 10 seconds i would also like video to still be displayed. i tried sleep(10000) but that pauses the programme so the code doesnt run cvShowImage.

Comment: @user170705: Do you mean you still want to display stuff, but at the same time wait 10 seconds. So practically, display stuff, but if it takes less than 10 seconds, wait up to 10 seconds after?

Comment: from the code above, i would like to detect the coloured balls until the white ball begins move. when the white ball begins to move i want to stop tracking the balls for 10 seconds and run a different piece of code and also keep displaying the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tip**: if you are going to share code, make sure it works. The idea is to always share a minimal example that reproduces the problem you are facing. This makes it easier for us to help you.

Since your code is incomplete I had to fill the missing pieces.

The code below retrieves frames from the camera, but I imagine your original code was reading from a video file. Anyway, the program below starts a 2nd thread (using pthreads) when a white ball is detected. It writes "White Ball detected" for 10 seconds and when the timer is done it writes "10sec passed".

Due to the lack of information, **the timer will only be fired once** during the lifetime of the application (after the the FIRST white ball is detected). I tried to make this procedure as simple as possible so you can change it if you want it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

// global variable manipulated by the 2nd thread
bool wait10sec = false;

void* timer_thread(void* arg)
{
    wait10sec = true;
    sleep(10);
    wait10sec = false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
    if (!capture)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "!!! Cannot initialize webcam!\n" );
      return -1;
    }

    cvNamedWindow("result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    IplImage* img = NULL;
    IplImage* gray = NULL;
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;
    int oldy = 0;
    int oldx = 0;

    // Variables used to control the timer
    bool white_ball_moved = false;
    pthread_t thread_id;

    // Variables used to write text over the image
    CvFont font;
    double hScale=1.0;
    double vScale=1.0;
    int    lineWidth=1;
    cvInitFont(&font,CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX|CV_FONT_ITALIC, hScale,vScale,0,lineWidth);

    char key = 0;
    while (key != 27) // ESC quits the application
    {
        img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (!img)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "!!! Failed to retrive frame!\n" );
            break;
        }

        cvShowImage("result", gray);

        if (!gray)
        {
            gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            if (!img)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "!!! Failed to allocate gray frame!\n" );
                break;
            }
        }

        cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 7, 45, 40,0,25);


        float* p;
        CvScalar s,t;
        int num_red = 15;


        for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
        {
            // round the floats to an int
            p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
            cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
            int radius = cvRound(p[2]);

            s = cvGet2D(img,center.y-6, center.x);
            t = cvGet2D(img,center.y, center.x);//colour of circle
            printf("\nB: %f G: %f R: %f\n",s.val[0],s.val[1],s.val[2]);

            if (s.val[2]<50 && s.val[1]<50 && s.val[0] <50)
            {
                printf("Black Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]>200 && s.val[1]>200 && s.val[0]>200)
            {
                printf("White Ball\n");
                xpos=center.x;
                ypos=center.y;
            }
            else if(s.val[2]>=250 && s.val[1]>=250 && s.val[0] <200)
            {
                printf("Yellow Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]<70 && s.val[1]>80 && s.val[0] <70)
            {
                printf("Green Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]>100 && s.val[1]<100 && s.val[0] <100)
            {
                printf("Brown Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]<100 && s.val[1]<100 && s.val[0] >100)
            {
                printf("Blue Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]>=250 && s.val[1]<250 && s.val[0] >=250)
            {
                printf("Pink Ball\n");
            }
            else if (s.val[2]<=255 && s.val[2]>=0 && s.val[1]<=255 && s.val[1]>=0 && s.val[0] <=255 && s.val[0]>=0)
            {
                printf("Red Ball\n");
                //num_red++;
            }

            // draw the circle center
            cvCircle(img, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );

            // draw the circle outline
            cvCircle(img, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );

            //display coordinates
            printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius);
        }

        printf("\nDetected %d balls\n", circles->total);

        if (white_ball_moved && wait10sec)
        {
            // white ball detected: execute this code for the next 10 seconds

            cvPutText (img, "White Ball detected", cvPoint(200,400), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
        }
        else if (white_ball_moved && !wait10sec)
        {
            // white ball was detected and 10 seconds have passed
            cvPutText (img, "10sec passed", cvPoint(200,400), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
        }

        if (!white_ball_moved)
        {
            if (xpos >= oldx + 10 || xpos<= oldx - 10 //wait for white ball movement here.
                && ypos >= oldy + 10 || ypos<= oldy - 10)
            {
                oldx = xpos;
                oldy = ypos;
                printf("White Ball Moving");

                white_ball_moved = true;

                // start 2nd thread to do the counting
                pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, timer_thread, NULL);
            }
        }

        cvShowImage("result", img);
        key = cvWaitKey(33);
    } // end of while, no more frames will be retrieved

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ balls.cpp -o balls -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lpthread
```

**EDIT:**

**Windows version:**

```
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

// global variable manipulated by the 2nd thread
bool wait10sec = false;

void timer_thread(void* arg)
{
    wait10sec = true;
    Sleep(10000); // 10s
    wait10sec = false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
    if (!capture)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "!!! Cannot initialize webcam!\n" );
      return -1;
    }

    cvNamedWindow("result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    IplImage* img = NULL;
    IplImage* gray = NULL;
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;
    int oldy = 0;
    int oldx = 0;

    // Variables used to control the timer
    bool white_ball_moved = false;

    // Variables used to write text over the image
    CvFont font;
    double hScale=1.0;
    double vScale=1.0;
    int    lineWidth=1;
    cvInitFont(&font,CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX|CV_FONT_ITALIC, hScale,vScale,0,lineWidth);

    char key = 0;
    while (key != 27) // ESC quits the application
    {
        img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (!img)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "!!! Failed to retrive frame!\n" );
            break;
        }

        cvShowImage("result", gray);

        if (!gray)
        {
            gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            if (!img)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "!!! Failed to allocate gray frame!\n" );
                break;
            }
        }

        cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 7, 45, 40,0,25);


        float* p;
        CvScalar s,t;
        int num_red = 15;


        for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
        {
            // round the floats to an int
            p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
            cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
            int radius = cvRound(p[2]);

            s = cvGet2D(img,center.y-6, center.x);
            t = cvGet2D(img,center.y, center.x);//colour of circle
            printf("\nB: %f G: %f R: %f\n",s.val[0],s.val[1],s.val[2]);

            if (s.val[2]<50 && s.val[1]<50 && s.val[0] <50)
            {
                printf("Black Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]>200 && s.val[1]>200 && s.val[0]>200)
            {
                printf("White Ball\n");
                xpos=center.x;
                ypos=center.y;
            }
            else if(s.val[2]>=250 && s.val[1]>=250 && s.val[0] <200)
            {
                printf("Yellow Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]<70 && s.val[1]>80 && s.val[0] <70)
            {
                printf("Green Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]>100 && s.val[1]<100 && s.val[0] <100)
            {
                printf("Brown Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]<100 && s.val[1]<100 && s.val[0] >100)
            {
                printf("Blue Ball\n");
            }
            else if(s.val[2]>=250 && s.val[1]<250 && s.val[0] >=250)
            {
                printf("Pink Ball\n");
            }
            else if (s.val[2]<=255 && s.val[2]>=0 && s.val[1]<=255 && s.val[1]>=0 && s.val[0] <=255 && s.val[0]>=0)
            {
                printf("Red Ball\n");
                //num_red++;               
            }

            // draw the circle center
            cvCircle(img, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );

            // draw the circle outline
            cvCircle(img, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );

            //display coordinates
            printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius);
        }

        printf("\nDetected %d balls\n", circles->total);

        if (white_ball_moved && wait10sec)
        {
            // white ball detected: execute this code for the next 10 seconds

            cvPutText (img, "White Ball detected", cvPoint(50,50), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
        }
        else if (white_ball_moved && !wait10sec)
        {
            // white ball was detected and 10 seconds have passed
            cvPutText (img, "10sec passed", cvPoint(50,50), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
        }

        if (!white_ball_moved)
        {
            if (xpos >= oldx + 10 || xpos<= oldx - 10 //wait for white ball movement here.
                && ypos >= oldy + 10 || ypos<= oldy - 10)
            {
                oldx = xpos;
                oldy = ypos;
                printf("White Ball Moving");

                white_ball_moved = true;

                // start 2nd thread to do the counting
                _beginthread(timer_thread, 0, NULL);
            }
        }

        cvShowImage("result", img);
        key = cvWaitKey(33);
    } // end of while, no more frames will be retrieved

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The mechanism to detect circles remains the same, so it isn't very efficient with my webcam and the scenario I have, but I managed to trigger a "white ball" event by moving my hand in front of the camera. Crazy, hun?!

Comment: Exactly, but the second thread has a life of approximately 10 seconds, then it dies.

Comment: if i was to have another piece or multiple pieces of code added above, could i not use the 2nd thread again?

Comment: you could start it again, yes. Please test my code, I think it exemplifies what you asked in the question.

Comment: pthread was undeclared when i compiled. i added the pthread.h header but that was not found. i am using windows. dont know what the problem is?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you didn't answer my previous comment right below your question, so I ended up coding a solution specific to Linux (as you can tell, just by looking at the compiling command I shared below the code). But I'm sure you are capable of converting the pthreads related code to use [native windows threads](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438/Introduction-to-Multi-threaded-Code). Read the *No Synchronization* section, is fairly easy to understand.

Comment: ive converted to windows and get  cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void *(__cdecl *)(void *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)' error?

Comment: Just change the signature of the timer_thread function, from `void* timer_thread(void* arg)` to `void timer_thread(void* pParams)`. **=P**

Comment: What is the line of the error? Without knowing it I can only guess. Please paste the entire line here.

Comment: 1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\image.c\image.c\image.cpp(216) : error C2664: '_beginthread' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void *(__cdecl *)(void *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'

Comment: I've tested it here, and that error goes away when you change the signature of the function to `void timer_thread(void* arg)`, just like I said earlier. The fact that you are still having it, demonstrates that you are not really paying attention to my comments. Good luck from now on.

Comment: it was because u had asterix after my void! didnt see the details. thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer to share code for the windows version as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding some state to your loop, and checking the time every time round. For example something like this using gettimeofday():

```
#include <sys/time.h>

int tracking_ball = 0;
struct timeval last_seen;

while (true) {
    if (tracking_ball) {
        struct timeval time_now;

        // do ball tracking here

        gettimeofday(&time_now, NULL);

        if (time_now.tv_sec - last_seen.tv_sec >= 10) {
            // 10 seconds went by, stop tracking
            tracking_ball = 0;
        }
    } else {
        // look for ball

        if (found the ball) {
            tracking_ball = 1;
            gettimeofday(&last_seen, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to use an alarm signal, but then you have to deal with signal handling and possibly getting interrupted during system calls.